# How to add a chatbot widget that uses Watson Conversation in my website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, widget, chatbot, watson-conversation

I want to add a chatbot in my web page like this one 
[chatbot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgM7C.png)

it should be at the bottom right of the web page.

i read a lot of guides:
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-bot?cm_mc_uid=55864532344114098377155&cm_mc_sid_50200000=

and a lot more, but i still can't figure out how to add Watson conversation as a chatbot widget in my website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Watson Conversation, but, try to read  the official documentation and get started with this Service.

Summary: You need to create one *Conversation* Service inside IBM Bluemix, and after, create one *Workspace* and teach you Chatbot.

And for add your chatbot in your Website, you need build one custom code for calling the Watson Conversation and creates one front-end for the conversation.

You can see this project from IBM Developers [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple) using Watson Conversation, this example uses Node.js and are developed by IBM.

- See this documentation about the [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/) (How to call, how to send message, etc)
- See this [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/index.html) about Watson Conversation Service.

Answer (score 0):

Check [chatlio.com](http://chatlio.com)

This is a nice and simple widget you can use in your website. It's built upon Slack, so you need to create a bot in Slack, and follow the simple `nodejs` code mentioned in Chatlio documentation.

It's a simple middleware that will listen to messages from user or Watson conversation, and posted it back to to the user, in the widget. It smart's to know who is the sender and who is the receiver.

Give it a try!